# Which layers should I freeze for fine tuning a resnet model on keras?

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network, keras, deep-learning

I already know how to do it on vgg (fine tuning the last conv block) and inception (fine tuning the top two blocks). I'd like to know which layers is recommended to freeze in order to fine tuning a resnet model.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I think that there is no a state of the art strategy for this but I may share you my thoughts on this topic (names of layers are similar to these presented [here](https://github.com/fchollet/keras/blob/master/keras/applications/resnet50.py):

1. In case of having a lot of data real-world photos: freeze all stages up to stage 4 (leave the only 5th trainable). If you overfit - make the 5th stage to have fewer layers. If underfit *unfreeze* a half of the fourth layer. Remember - the deeper into the network - the more *ImageNet* specific features you have.
2. In case of having a few real-world photos: cut 5th, leave half of 4th stage trainable and freeze the rest. If overfit - keep cutting stage 4th, if underfit - keep extending.
3. In case of having a lot of simple photos data (e.g. medical ones) - cut 4th and 5th - leave 3rd trainable and freeze the rest. If overfit - keep cutting - id underfit - try point 2.
4. In case of having a few simple (less than 10K) photos data - I would advise not to use `ResNet50`. From my experience it overfits severely. I usually implement my custom topologies similar to `ResNet18`. If you still want to try it - try instructions from 3rd point.

Comment: Do you know which layers those are in keras?

Comment: thanks @Marcin for your answer. Small remark: the hyperlink you provided in the first sentence is not valid anymore

Comment: @TommasoDiNoto there is a new implementation of Resent50(v2). You can access it [here](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/keras/applications/resnet_v2.py)